# Cetma Front Rack Clamp Part?

Tags: rack, front

I just bought a used Cetma front rack and I'm looking for these types of "clamps". I need the right diameter for BMX handlebars so 22.2mm I believe in diameter (7/8 inch). Does anyone know what they are called so I can't search for them online or ask for them in a hardware store? I kind of assume these are some kind of standard off the shelf parts I can get and not custom made by the guy who makes Cetma racks.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Found out those "clamps" are called **conduit hangers**:

https://www.homedepot.com/p/2-ACC-Conduit-Hanger-67820/202077114

Comment: Nice work - excellent knowledge sharing.  The caveats, for a 93 cent item it won't be particularly rust resistant, so use assembly grease.  The edges could score your bars, more so if mounted near or on a bend so consider using a layer of bartape or something around the bars.  Finally, there's a lot of vibration on a bike, so use a crinkle washer, or lock two nuts together, or threadlocker to stop the whole thing coming loose.  And that adds some level of theft defence too.

Comment: The bolts in your image look to be stainless steel, whereas the homedepot link has cheaper bolts.

Comment: @Criggie Thanks for the heads up about material. I didn't pay attention to that at all. The details about how to deal with the vibrations and rust are much appreciated.